# How to identify the xpath for an element that has the same URL appended with page name

Tags: selenium, xpath, cypress

I'm trying to find the xpath on a home page that contains menu with multiple items.

```
<a href="https://test.com/en/" aria-current="page">HOME</a>
<a href="https://test.com/en/blog/">BLOG</a>
<a href="https://test.com/en/resources/">RESOURCES</a>
```

The language might change when translation test is done.
For eg: [BLOG](https://test.com/**esp**/blog/)

below works for English

```
a[@href,"https://test.firework.tv/en/"]
```

But when language changes it fails. Is there a wild card that I can use similar to below?

```
//a[@href,"https://test.firework.tv/*/"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  //a[starts-with(@href, ‘https://test.com/’) and ends-with(@href, ‘blog/’)]
```

THe above one finds blog

```
 //a[starts-with(@href, ‘https://test.com/’)]
```

The above finds all ( its equalent to //a[@href,"https://test.firework.tv/*/*"]

You can use above first syntax  all endpoints except home, for home use OR

```
//a[@href= ‘https://test.com/en/' or @href= ‘https://test.com/lt/']
```

Comment: The first one is good. Deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to  `//a[starts-with(@href, ‘https://test.com/’)`

```
//a[contains(@href, 'https://test.com/')]
```